# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again in IntelliJ IDEA for Scala-Spark Program using SBT

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDBroadcast extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val states = Map(("NY","New York"),("CA","California"),("FL","Florida"))
  val countries = Map(("USA","United States of America"),("IN","India"))

  val broadcastStates = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(states)
  val broadcastCountries = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(countries)

  val data = Seq(("James","Smith","USA","CA"),
    ("Michael","Rose","USA","NY"),
    ("Robert","Williams","USA","CA"),
    ("Maria","Jones","USA","FL")
  )

  val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

  val rdd2 = rdd.map(f=>{
    val country = f._3
    val state = f._4
    val fullCountry = broadcastCountries.value(country)
    val fullState = broadcastStates.value(state)
    (f._1,f._2,fullCountry,fullState)
  })

  println(rdd2.collect().mkString("\n"))

}
```

The above is the spark-scala code to get country and state names. While compiling the code in InteliJ IDEA, I'm getting Error as below:

```
*Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more*
```

I've tried multiple solutions like checking the java and javac version but the versions are in sync.
[Click here to view the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgqxY.png)

I've also checked the java version in the project File->project Structure...-> Module and compared it with Run->Edit Configurations which is also matching.

Build.sbt code: [Click here to view the sbt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh0zC.png)

I'm using VMware workstation 16 Player on which inteliJ is installed in linux OS. java version is **1.8.0_301**

[Click Here to view the InteliJ IDE in Linux Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Cf1.png)

Answer (score 7):

I have faced the same issue, resolved it by setting Run/Debug Configurations -> Modify Options -> Java -> Add dependencies with provided scope to classpath to YES